# Add campden and bottle right away or should I wait?

Tags: bottling, wine, campden

I know that we should add campden before bottling wine. My question is, I need to add it 1 day prior to bottling or can I add campden and bottle right away. I am afraid of cork popping because if I remember correctly campden may release some gas.

- A) Add Campden and bootling
- B) Add Campden, wait 24h, and bootling

Comment: More information about your recipe and process would help get a better answer.  Wine from grapes or from a kit?  How long was your wine in the fermenter? In secondary vessel?

Comment: @Philippe from grapes, 3/4 days of fermentation with kveik yeast, 3/4 months in secondary.  Botling after that.

Answer (score 3):

"should add campden tablets before bottling wine" might be a bit of an exaggeration, though they can be beneficial in case you want an extra insurance that nothing will go wrong while your wine ages in bottles.

You can add the tablets as little as 30 minutes before you bottle. I wouldn't do it too long before bottling though, as that could also allow bad stuff to potentially re-enter your brew before bottling

Answer (score 1):

You don't *have* to add Campden, only if your recipe calls for it or if you plan to age your wine and preserve it for a longer period of time.  Remember that metabisulphite is naturally present in grape must and its purpose is to protect your wine from oxygen.  The recommended amount of free SO2 in a wine is between 25mg/L and 50mg/L which can be tricky to acheive if you don't have the tools to measure it...

Now this being said, crushing a campden tablet and mixing it in a little water prior to adding it to wine shouldn't produce too much gas.  However, if you wine still has some CO2 in suspension, you should degass it before bottling.

So, I wouldn't wait 24h, but I would mix it thourougly before bottling.

Comment: I had a previous experience with a spoiled batch after some months. I am talking about 200 liters, so I prefer a safe measure of adding Campden after each racking and before bottling.

Comment: Absolutely, that is why I was asking more information about your process.  The more your rack your wine, the more air gets introduced and Metabisulfite getrs depleted.  Also aging/stabilizing for months is totally different than bottling after 4 weeks (wine kits).  Adding more Campden is right for you.